# I created an audio-focused puzzle game, and you should give it a shot. :)

Tags: sound-design, game

Not so much a question, but rather a personal project which I believe the audio community could certainly appreciate!  ...well, actually it's a project *only* the audio community could appreciate... :D

[www.phonopath.com](http://www.phonopath.com)

Phonopath is free-to-play, and the gameplay is as follows:  Download a sound clip, manipulate it to find your password, and advance to the next stage.  Puzzle concepts span basic processing, spectrograms, cryptography, music, etc...

It was released last month, and received a ton of solid feedback from sound geeks all over.  Check it out if you got some time - it's pretty fresh stuff. :)

Answer (score 1):

Very cool. I did the first two, not sure I'll be bothered to go much further, but I think audio schools would absolutely lap this up. I'm going to forward it to a teacher mate of mine now. I think it'd perfect to give them for a homework.

edit: urgh, I can't make out what the woman is saying from the lack of bit depth. shark? chalk? chock? Also, if i'm supposed to be listening, then make it really easy to turn off that back ground music.

edit^2: Also I think you need some sort of cookie based thing that drops people back where they had progressed to, that unskipable intro is not necessary to hear more then once.

Comment: Quick heads-up: The music is only present when the password box is active. :)

Comment: well it's very cool. I'd like to know a list of the different tricks you used, but I get if you'd not like to give it away on a public site.

Comment: Well, I'm considering doing a video walkthrough of the entire game soon... and if you want to browse the game without suffering through all the puzzles, you can use the info below:

Username: Demo
Email: Blank
PIN: 1234

Comment: What are you hearing more than once?  There definitely is a cookie based thing in there, and the username/PIN should be enough to track your progress otherwise...

Comment: Liking the idea, but I agree with Reon that listening to the intro every time is very tedious. I also can't work out what the woman is saying in the first 'hello player' game!
The level of the music when you are typing in the password, in my opinion, is too loud and I would like to turn this off  to be honest.


Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I'll look into a "Music off" option...but I'm still unsure about why you guys are hearing the intro more than once, and obviously I'd love to resolve it.  Are you talking about the intro clip upon entering the door?  ("Aight cool, so before we get started, check it out...etc.")

Answer (score 1):

Holy cow, what fun! Loved the end of phase one, what a neat idea.